# Heatsink too big

Tags: cooling

The passive cooling set I ordered has 1 big and 2 medium heatsinks. Would it do any harm if I used the medium heatsink for the capacitor? For the Raspberry Pi B+ it should have been 1 big, 1 medium and 1 small heatsink to fit perfectly.

Comment: It won't hurt anything so long as it does not short to another component or cause mechanical failure of the mounting or soldered joints - both unlikely. However, the Pi does not require any additional cooling.

Comment: Thanks! As far as I can see it won't touch anything else, so I'm good to go I guess. I planned on OCing to around 840Mhz, cooling can't hurt either I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would like to mention, capacitors generally don't require heatsinks and should have the ambient room temperature, unless you're using them in a totally unpredictable way.

Secondly, there's absolutely nothing wrong with using large heatsinks, but you ought to be careful about 1) heatsink touching other parts -- this might lead to shorts and permanent damage, and 2) heatsink falling off because of being too heavy and glue area being too small with subsequent shorts on the board and permanent damage.

Comment: I am a more or less experienced overclocker when it comes to computers. Never cooled capacitors there, so I didn't know how to handle this and I certainly didn't want to break my newly bought pi. Thanks for your answer! Point 2, heatsink could fall off is what I figured. I'll leave it be.